# c# asp.net website calling a webApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, httpresponsemessage

I meet a problem because of my inexperience managing Threads.
I have this Action bellow :

```
 public static async Task<joueurs> loadjoueurs(int id)
        {
            joueurs EmpInfo = new joueurs();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //Passing service base url  
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.myWebApi.fr/api/");

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                //Define request data format  
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  
                HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("joueurs?id=" + id);

                //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
                 if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                  {
                      //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                      var EmpResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                      //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list  
                       EmpInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<joueurs>(EmpResponse);
                      return EmpInfo;
                  }

                return null;
            }
```

it s just client to get my data from a webApi (no ssl no authentication, when I test it I receive the right values)
but when I make a call using the function above (in my asp.net website) .... it stay stucked at the HttpResponseMessage = await .... eternally.

In my webApi I have two functions same name but different parameters .

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Getjoueur(int iduser, int idsport)
```

and

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Getjoueur(int id)
```

So I am don't know where the problem comes from.

(sequel) Here is the place where I call the Task :

```
public SuperModel(int id)
        {
            this.joueur =  Repojoueurs.loadjoueurs(id).Result;
       /*     this.classificationSport =  Repoclassificationsport.loadclassificationsport().Result;
             ...
       */
        }
```

And then my Supermodel is instantiated here in my Home controller  :

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            SuperModel superModel = new SuperModel(id);


            return View(superModel);
        }
```

Comment: Any information on how and where you call Task<joueurs> loadjoueurs(int id)?

Comment: ... and apparently using Fiddler I know my webApi returns the expected data. So I don't know why it keeps stucked here.

Comment: yes of course, I call the method in a constructor of a 'Myclass' (which is the model I pass to my  return View('Myclass')). ... in the action which return the View.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try not to use the *async* and *wait*. Around three changes like below

```
public static HttpResponseMessage loadjoueurs(int id)
    {

            HttpResponseMessage Res = client.GetAsync("joueurs?id=" + id);

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,EmpInfo, "application/json");
     }
```

Comment: HttpClient only propose async method ... and frankly async is pretty vital in my project.

Comment: salut ! i've found it !  here is the solution :  HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("joueurs?id=" + id).ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: Glad that you've found it. On the other hand, you are right HttpClient only proposes async, however, you still can call it without await. Good Luck.